# Knockout JS listing, binding historical details with custom binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

i have a list of data
user will click on any row and display it details

the previous user selection will be saved, proceeding with triggering a custom bind to call ajax to retrieve data

```
  var jsondata = [{
       "xxd": "1",
           "r_xd": "1",
           "fxd": 1,
           "dtxd": 1,
           "drxd": 1,
           "dsxd": 1,
           "x_ther": "1",
           "x_therslutxn": "1",
           "x_xsnd": true,
           "x_xsfxxed": true,
           "x_lat": "1",
           "x_ln": "1",
           "x_delete": false,
           "x_deldate": "2013-12-02T00:00:00",
           "s_c_by": 1
   }, {
       "xxd": "2",
           "r_xd": "2",
           "fxd": 2,
           "dtxd": 2,
           "drxd": 2,
           "dsxd": 1,
           "x_ther": "3",
           "x_therslutxn": "4",
           "x_xsnd": true,
           "x_xsfxxed": true,
           "x_lat": "1",
           "x_ln": "1",
           "x_delete": false,
           "x_deldate": "2013-12-02T00:00:00",
           "s_c_by": 321
   }];

   //-----------------get historical data
   //jQuery.support.cors = true;
   ko.bindingHandlers.history = {
       init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
           console.log('-------init history---------');
           //console.dir(element);
           var primaryId = valueAccessor();
           //console.log(primaryId);

           var itemData = null;
           // JSON RETURN DATA  

           $.post("/echo/json/", {
               json: JSON.stringify(jsondata)
           },

           function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               console.log('getJSON');
               console.dir(data);
               new HistoryRowViewModel(data);
           });
       }
   };


   function HistoryRowViewModel(data) {
       //this.history = ko.observable(); 
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, historymapping, vm.historys);
   }
   var historymapping = {
       key: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
           return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data);
       },
       create: function (options) {
           console.log(options.data);
           return HistoryRowViewModel(options.data);
       }
   }
```

my viewmodel returns me as follow : {"historys":[null,null]}

with

```
     <table id="historical" data-bind="history:vm.primaryid()">      
    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(vm), null, 2)"></pre>       
      <thead>    
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent">           
          <!--  <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data)), null, 2)"></pre> -->   
          <th data-bind="text:$data">
          </th>          
        </tr>      
      </thead>                      
      <tbody>              
        <!-- ko foreach: vm.historys() -->       
        <tr data-bind="foreach: vm.historys()">                   
          <!-- ko foreach: $parent -->       
          <!--<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>    -->       
          <td data-bind="text:$data.incidentid"> </td>                                
          <!-- /ko -->                          
        </tr>                             
        <!-- /ko -->                        
      </tbody>                  
    </table>
```

is this a fault with mybinding ?      history:vm.primaryid()

the valueAccessor() returns the primaryid I pass it and i was able to query it

my intention is to push every single rows return from the jsondata

and bind it to my view.

How do i achieve this? 
is my concept wrong?

i have posted it to (http://jsfiddle.net/sigibb/NsNvc/1/) but is not working.. I dont know how to bind it with out the other dependencies.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Apart from many spelling issues, missing interpunction (use an automated spellchecker if you need it), missing [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), your actual problem isn't clear. What is your specific question? Try to boil it down to one particular question, and write follow-up questions if you need. In addition, it would help if your example/fiddle would have only *one* issue (the one you're trying to solve), currently there are just too many things not working (e.g. see the console for JS errors). Good luck!

Comment: also, what is a pre tag doing directly inside a table tag? Just curious! That layout is wrong!

Comment: @Jeroen .. sorry i will refine it without other dependencies.

Comment: @SujeshArukil the pre is my debug code. did not remove it because that's how i can show the output at the moment.